# Troubles storing with laravel (Undefined property)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to store data to the server with laravel. I am following a tutorial and I feel like it may be slightly out of date because I was getting a 500 error earlier with an update method.

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::json();

    return Player::create(array( 
        'teamName' => $input->teamName, // this is line 35
        'teamColor' => $input->teamColor
    ));
}
```

The above is what the tutorial's syntax is like, I tried the below as well.

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    return Player::create(array( 
        'teamName' => $input['teamName'], // this is line 35
        'teamColor' => $input['teamColor']
    ));
}
```

Inside the browser I get this error.

`{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined property: Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ParameterBag::$teamName","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\basketball-app-framework\\app\\controllers\\PlayersController.php","line":35}}`

So I feel like these issues I should be able to figure out in a matter of seconds, but I am new and really don't know where to find a clear answer. I tried searching the docs, but I can't find what I am looking for, maybe I am being blind?

Comment: Could you execute ´dd($input = Input::all())´ and show us the result?

Comment: yeah one second brb. I executed it, where do I see the response? Is it the response_text the POST method returns?

Comment: array (size=2)
  'teamName' => string 'Bulls' (length=5)
  'teamColor' => string '' (length=0) I am pretty sure this is the right response returned.

Comment: Another error I get when playing around is `{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Trying to get property of non-object","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\basketball-app-framework\\app\\controllers\\PlayersController.php","line":33}}`

Comment: This code gave me the error above `$input = Input::all();
  return Player::create(array('teamName' => $input->teamName ));`

Comment: This instruction: $input = Input::all(); Will return an array, so $input->teamName really should return an error. Just added an answer with a third form of usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
public function store()
{
    return Player::create(array( 
        'teamName' => Input::get('teamName'),
        'teamColor' => Input::get('teamColor')
    ));
}
```

Getting a mass assignment error, means that you need to edit your model and add the $fillable variable to it:

```
class Player extends Eloquent {

   protected $fillable = array('teamName', 'teamColor');

}
```

Laravel tries to protect you from mass assignments, so you have to tell it which columns are ok to mass assign.

Request (Input) docs: http://laravel.com/docs/requests.

CheatSheet: http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/.

Mass assignment: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment.

Comment: Oh thanks man, I didn't know about `Input::get` is this somewhere in the laravel docs. Is there a source or cheatsheet I can look at if I need ideas for different ways to interact with data?

Comment: Documentation for Input is here: http://laravel.com/docs/requests. And here is a cheatsheet: http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/.

Comment: Okay thanks, I need to figure out a better strategy in searching the docs. I am still getting an error though `{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\MassAssignmentException","message":"teamName","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\basketball-app-framework\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php","line":333}}` Maybe I need to check a few things under the hood, thanks so much for the help though. Almsot there I can feel it

Comment: Yup!! Wish I could read those error messages better, thanks so much man! Is this due to an update in laravel or something, why do I have to do this and the instructor in the tutorial not have to? I am definitely going to read about the $fillable variable. But if you would like to provide some brief insight that would be awesome.

Comment: Okay I see your insight above, thanks. Is this due to a newer version, I am curious to know why the instructor didn't have to do that, I am assuming this is a new add-on, ill figure that out anyway. I really am not sure how this is defined as a mass assignment though? but whatever it's working so I can move on, I need to learn this stuff for later. Glad to have this community available, thanks!